# Which member of a global union variable that is not initialized explicitly will be initialized to 0 implicitly?

Tags: c, initialization, unions

e.g.

```
union
{
    int n;
    void *p;
} u;
```

Is the initial value of u.n or that of u.p equal to 0?

It should be noted that a NULL pointer is not necessarily stored in all-zero bits. Therefore, even if u.n and u.p have the same size,

```
u.n == 0
```

doesn't guarantee

```
u.p == 0
```

and vice versa.

(Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `u` is static then the first member will be initialized to `zero`, from the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.8` *Initialization* paragraph *10*:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If **an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then**:
>
> > — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> >
> > — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> >
> > — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
> >
> > — **if it is a union**, the **first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.**

since `n` is a `arithmetic type` it will be initialized to `zero`. The value of `p` is unspecified but in practice type punning is usually supported by the compiler for example the [gcc manual points here for Type-punning](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Type_002dpunning.html#Type_002dpunning) and we can see under *-fstrict-aliasing* section is says:

> The practice of reading from a different union member than the one most recently written to (called “type-punning”) is common. Even with -fstrict-aliasing, type-punning is allowed, provided the memory is accessed through the union type.

It is also worth noting that you `may` be able to initialize any member of a union like so:

```
union { int n; void *p; } u = { .p = NULL } ;
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am not sure if all compilers support this though.

Answer (score 3):

if Object with Static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:

— if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;

— if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;

— if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;

— if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.

So `u.n` will be initilaized to zero and `u.p` is undetermined.

**EDIT: Response to comment**

above info copied from ISO/IEC 9899:201x **6.7.9.10**

Comment: It looks like you copied this from the standard. If so, it would be good to also provide a link or reference to the applicable section.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is a static object to me.

Answer (score -1):

I think by 'global variable' you mean that it's at file scope. If so, and if it's declared 'static', it will be initialized to all zero bits, eg because it gets allocated in .BSS.
What those zero bits in the union's storage mean in terms of the value of whichever of its members you access depends on their types. In your case, all zero bits in an int means it has the value zero, and all zero bits in a pointer makes it NULL, ie @Dukeling's bang on here.
I am not sure that all zero bits in a float would yield a float with value zero.

Comment: The most common way of representing a NULL pointer is as all zero bits, but it seems that the standard doesn't require this (this is implied at a few resources).

Comment: True, however the fact that the standard doesn't forbid something doesn't mean that it's reasonable.

In the draft standard linked above, section 6.3.2.3 para 3 says:

An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
`void *`, is called a null pointer constant.

An implementation that complied, but which gave such a null pointer constant a representation other than all-zero bits, would be surprising, to say the least.

Answer (score -1):

It depends upon how you instantiate the variable itself. Usually static defined variables are initialized to zero. If you malloc the union to a pointer, you may get uninitialized memory. However, if you use calloc to allocate memory for the union, calloc will initialized the allocated memory to zero per the man page.

It may also depend on any libraries that you may be using. Google's perftools library may or may not zero out the memory when you make the call to calloc that it overwrites.